# WordPress Подключение стилей только для определенных типов записей и их потомков

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, как подключать стили в шапке сайта, для определенных типов записи. Приведу пример подключения в файле functions.php

```
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'front_scripts');
function front_scripts()
{ wp_enqueue_style('main-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.min.css','', null, false);

    /// TODO Не правильно отдает стили на странице всех обзоров. Лишнее
    if ( ! is_home() && get_post()->post_name =='reviews' || array('post_type' => 'reviews', get_the_ID() ) ){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'onlyForReviews', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/onlyReviews/onlyReviews.css', array( 'main-css' ), null, false );
    }
}
```

Тут фаил с id="main-css" подключается для всех страниц, а фаил стилей с id="onlyForReviews" только для типов записи post_type ="reviews" Но у меня не правильно отрабатывает правая часть функции после логического "ИЛИ".  (`|| array('post_type' => 'reviews', get_the_ID() ))`  Мне необходимо что б страницы с URL `http://simplesite.com/reviews/что-то-там-ещё` тоже получали доступ в файлу onlyReviews.css. И только они

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'front_scripts');
function front_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('main-css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/main.min.css', '', null, false);

    if (is_post_type_archive("reviews") || is_singular("reviews") ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'onlyForReviews', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/onlyReviews/onlyReviews.css', array( 'main-css' ), null, false );
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, is_singular("reviews") помогло. Первая часть проверки не сработала

Comment: Первая часть для архивной страницы на которой все посты выводятся